# Why am I getting duplicate links ? And how do I fetch links on the next pages?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am getting duplicate links when for the links I am trying to obtain, I am not sure why. Also I am trying to fetch all the links like the ones I am getting from all the pages. But I am not sure how to write the code to click next page. Could someone please help me understand how I would go about this?

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams'
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

#all_teams = []

for team_links in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if team_links['href'] == '' or team_links['href'].startswith('/counterstrike/teams'):
       print (team_links.get('href').replace('/counterstrike/teams', url))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The team links are in *anchor* tags inside the *h3* tags which are inside the *div* with the *details* class:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin
base = "http://www.gosugamers.net"
url = 'http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams'
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for team_links in soup.select("div.details h3 a"):
    print ( urljoin(base, team_links["href"]))
```

Which gives you:

```
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16338-motv
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16337-absolute-monster
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16258-immortals-cs
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16251-ireal-star-gaming
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16176-team-genesis
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16175-potadies
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16174-crowns-gg
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16173-visomvet
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16172-team-phenomenon
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16152-kriklekrakle
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16148-begenius
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16144-blubblub
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16142-team-1231
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16141-vsv
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16140-tbi
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16136-deadweight
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16135-me-myself-and-i
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16085-pur-esports
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15850-falken
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15815-team-abyssal
```

You are literally parsing all the links on the page, that is why you see the dupes.

To get all the teams we can parse the next page link until the span with the `"Next"` text is not there any more which only happens for the last page:

```
def get_all(url, base):
    r = requests.get(url)
    page = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    for team_links in soup.select("div.details h3 a"):
        yield (urljoin(base, team_links["href"]))
    nxt = soup.find("div", {"class": "pages"}).find("span", text="Next")
    while nxt:
        r = requests.get(urljoin(base, nxt.find_previous("a")["href"]))
        page = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        for team_links in soup.select("div.details h3 a"):
            yield (urljoin(base, team_links["href"]))
        nxt = soup.find("div", {"class": "pages"}).find("span", text="Next")
```

If we run it for a couple of seconds, you can see we get the next pages:

```
In [26]: for link in (get_all(url, base)):
   ....:         print(link)
   ....:     
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16386-cantonese-cs
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16338-motv
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16337-absolute-monster
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16258-immortals-cs
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16251-ireal-star-gaming
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16176-team-genesis
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16175-potadies
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16174-crowns-gg
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16173-visomvet
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16172-team-phenomenon
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16152-kriklekrakle
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16148-begenius
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16144-blubblub
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16142-team-1231
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16141-vsv
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16140-tbi
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16136-deadweight
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16135-me-myself-and-i
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/16085-pur-esports
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15850-falken
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15815-team-abyssal
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15810-ex-deathtrap
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15808-mix123
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15651-undertake-esports
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15644-five
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15630-five
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15627-inetkoxtv
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15626-tetr-s
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15625-rozenoir-esports-white
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15619-fragment-gg
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15615-monarchs-gg
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15602-ottoman-fire
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15591-respect
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15569-moonbeam-gaming
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15563-team-tilt
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15534-dynasty-uk
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15507-urbantech
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15374-innova
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15373-g3x
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15372-cnb
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15370-intz
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15369-2kill
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15368-supernova
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15367-biggods
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15366-playzone
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15365-pride
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15359-rising-orkam
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15342-team-foxez
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15336-angels
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15331-atlando-esports
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15329-xfinity-esports
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15326-nano-reapers
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15322-erase-team
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15318-heyguys
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15317-illusory
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15285-dismay
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15284-kingdom-esports
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15283-team-rival
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15282-ze-pug-godz
http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/15281-unlimited-potential1
```

You can see in the source for the first and any bar the last page the span with `Next`:

[image]

And when we get to the last, there is only spans with *Previous* and *First*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot. I will also look into the new functions that I haven't seen before!

Comment: No prob, the selects use css selectors, you could just chain find and find_all but I don't like typing so I prefer the conciseness of a selector when possible.